# sencha phonegap build apk error

Tags: android, sencha-touch, phonegap-desktop-app

i'am trying to get my apk file from sencha touch Project created with sencha architect so i use the next command in my application path :

1- sencha phonegap init : i add in the app.json the platform andoird:

```
"native": {
        "packager": "phonegap",
        "phonegap" : {
            "config": {
                // Uncomment the line below and add the platform you wish to build for
                "platform": "android",

                // Uncomment and Set this line to true to enable PhoneGap Remote Building.
                // To properly use this you must set the following properties in your local.properties file (if this file does not exist create it in your app root)
                // phonegap.remote.username=myname@domain.com
                // phonegap.remote.password=mys3cr3tp@ssw0rd
                //"remote":false,

                "id": "com.domain.MyApp",
                "name": "MyApp"
            }
        }
```

2 - sencha app build -run native : but dasn't work . 
error : [image error](http://imageshack.com/a/img538/7370/uz8mP8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try giving your entire project folder full read/write permissions.
2. Try downgrading your cordova CLI version.